# browser pop up is not closing in selenium

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, window, alerts

After launching the url there is a email pop up that i am trying to close. i have written xpath and able to find the close icon with that. but when i am trying to execute it is not closing. then i added implicitly wait for the element to be visible and then trying to close. still it is not closing. 
Can you please tell me what would be the reasons for such cases and how it can be solved.
and Submit button is also not clicking i have given the correct xpath.

Thanks in advance..

below is the code snippet.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {            
        WebDriver driver;
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:\\Softwares\\Chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://html.com/input-type-file/");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);    
        WebElement closeButon = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='om-close miami-element-close miami-close']"));     

        if(closeButon.isDisplayed())
        {
            System.out.println("close Buton is there.. ");
            closeButon.click();
            System.out.println("close Buton closed ");
        }
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='fileupload']")).sendKeys("E:\\Users\\laxman_p\\Desktop\\PromoFeature.txt");
        //Submit button
```

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='post-206']/div/div[3]/form/input[2]")).click();
        }

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once e.g.  **_email pop ... not closing_**, **_and Submit button is also not clicking_**. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

If you cant close it by xpath, 
I think this issue can be related with focused window,
You need to use getWindowHandle and switchTo methods to focus this pop-up. 
After that you will be able to make process on this pop-up.

```
 driver.getWindowHandles()
```

returns set of windows.

```
 driver.switchTo.window(windowId);
```

will switch you to window which you want to focus on.